# Linkedin API - data-callback IE8

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/javascript-bug-apply-linkedin-when-using-data-callback

That post explains my problem perfectly, no one has an answer so far as I can tell. Whenever I specify data-callback for LinkedIN's Apply API, IE8 gets Javascript errors and the callback breaks. Has anyone ran into this problem before?

Comment: That appears to be an undocumented (and therefore unsupported) option: https://developer.linkedin.com/apply-reference-guide

Answer (score 0):

IE6,7 & 8 all have only partial support for dataset's and data-* attributes within the HTML. It's the same for having the placeholder attribute which is not supported.

Read more here: http://caniuse.com/dataset

The main problem is that IE cannot read the attributes properly and reads them in html form only, thus cancelling out the Javascript.

A possible workaround is to set the attribute once the DOM has been initialized, though i have not had to try this out but I've read elsewhere it works. Something along the lines of this:

```
<script>document.getElementById('#ieTest').setAttribute('data-attribute', 'Damn you IE8!');</script>
```